# How to create all possible variations from single string presented in special format?

Tags: algorithm, parsing, text

Let's say, I have following template.

```
Hello, {I'm|he is} a {notable|famous} person.
```

Result should be

```
Hello, I'm a notable person.
Hello, I'm a famous person.
Hello, he is a notable person.
Hello, he is a famous person.
```

The only possible solution I have in mind - full search, but it is not effective.
May be there is a good algorithm for such kind of job but I do not know what task about. All permutations in array is very close to this but I have no idea how to use it here.

Here is working solution (it's part of object, so here is only relevant part).

generateText() parses string and converts `'Hello, {1|2}, here {3,4}'` into `['Hello', ['1', '2'], 'here', ['3', '4']]]`

extractText() takes this multidimensional array and creates all possible strings

```
        STATE_TEXT: 'TEXT',
        STATE_INSIDE_BRACKETS: 'INSIDE_BRACKETS',

        generateText: function(text) {
            var result = [];
            var state = this.STATE_TEXT;
            var length = text.length;
            var simpleText = '';
            var options = [];
            var singleOption = '';
            var i = 0;

            while (i < length) {
                var symbol = text[i];

                switch(symbol) {
                    case '{':
                        if (state === this.STATE_TEXT) {
                            simpleText = simpleText.trim();
                            if (simpleText.length) {
                                result.push(simpleText);
                                simpleText = '';
                            }
                            state = this.STATE_INSIDE_BRACKETS;
                        }
                        break;
                    case '}':
                        if (state === this.STATE_INSIDE_BRACKETS) {
                            singleOption = singleOption.trim();
                            if (singleOption.length) {
                                options.push(singleOption);
                                singleOption = '';
                            }
                            if (options.length) {
                                result.push(options);
                                options = [];
                            }
                            state = this.STATE_TEXT;
                        }
                        break;
                    case '|':
                        if (state === this.STATE_INSIDE_BRACKETS) {
                            singleOption = singleOption.trim();
                            if (singleOption.length) {
                                options.push(singleOption);
                                singleOption = '';
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (state === this.STATE_TEXT) {
                            simpleText += symbol;
                        } else if (state === this.STATE_INSIDE_BRACKETS) {
                            singleOption += symbol;
                        }
                        break;
                }

                i++;
            }

            return result;
        },

        extractStrings(generated) {
            var lengths = {};
            var currents = {};
            var permutations = 0;
            var length = generated.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if ($.isArray(generated[i])) {
                    lengths[i] = generated[i].length;
                    currents[i] = lengths[i];
                    permutations += lengths[i];
                }
            }

            var strings = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < permutations; i++) {
                var string = [];
                for (var k = 0; k < length; k++) {
                    if (typeof lengths[k] === 'undefined') {
                        string.push(generated[k]);
                        continue;
                    }

                    currents[k] -= 1;
                    if (currents[k] < 0) {
                        currents[k] = lengths[k] - 1;
                    }
                    string.push(generated[k][currents[k]]);
                }

                strings.push(string.join(' '));
            }

            return strings;
        },
```

Comment: That depends in the exact use case. Are these templates predefined or limited in some way. Do you only search in one _"small”_ text or do you have multiple text units to search in. Do those texts vary often or rarely, ... .

Comment: There can be many lines, and every line can have thousands of {a|b|c} templates

Comment: Bash (and some other shells) have rhis functionality built-in, although you need to use `,` instead of `|` to separate alternatives, and some amount of quoting will also be necessary. Try, for example, `printf '%s\n' "Hello, "{"I'm","he is"}" a "{notable,famous}" person."`.

Comment: By the way, if you have a thousand parallel templates of even two alternatives each, you are going to require a CPU capable of surviving the eventual heat death of the universe in order to enumerate the possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only possible solution I have in mind - full search, but it is not effective.

If you must provide full results, you must run full search. There is simply no way around it. You don't need all permutations, though: the number of results is equal to the product of the number of alternatives in each template.

Although there are multiple ways to implement this, recursion is among the most popular approaches. Here is some pseudo-code to get you started:

```
string[][] templates = {{"I'm", "he is"}, {"notable", "famous", "boring"}}
int[] pos = new int[templates.Length]
string[] fills = new string[templates.Length]
recurse(templates, fills, 0)
...
void recurse(string[][] templates, string[] fills, int pos) {
    if (pos == fills.Length) {
        formatResult(fills);
    } else {
        foreach option in templates[pos] {
            fills[pos] = option
            recurse(templates, fills, pos+1);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the best solution here is going to be `n*m` where `n=the first array` and `m= the second array` . There are n*m required lines of output, which means that as long as you are only doing n*m you aren't doing any extra work

The generic running time for this is where there is more than 2 arrays with options, it would be

n<sub>1</sub>*n<sub>2</sub>...*n<sub>m</sub> where each of those is equal to the size of the respective list

A nested loop where you just print out the value for the current index of the outer loop along with the current value for the index of the inner loop should do this properly